# R Prompt User for Number Input

Tags: r, user-input

I'm trying to write an R script that asks the user to input a number that will be stored for later use. I'm struggling with storing the value though. Below is what I have written.

```
numberOfStudents <- function()
{
s <- readline("How many incoming students are there? ")
return(as.integer(s))
}
print(numberOfStudents())
print(s)
```

If I store 500 as the value after running print(numberOfStudents()), print(s) returns "Error in print(s) : object 's' not found".

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just like anything else in R, you need to assign the result of your function: `result <- numberOfStudents()`. It doesn't matter what the variable names are inside the function, only what you name you use when you assign the result. If you want it to be named `s`, then use `s <- numberOfStudents()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there.

The problem is that you save the input in a variable inside the function, and print it out, but you never expressly tell the function to save the variable to the outside world.

The function numberOfStudents is inside your current enviroment. SO you might consider a few things, but the best idea is to return a value to the current environment and assign it.

```
numberOfStudents <- function()
{
s <- readline("How many incoming students are there? ")
return(as.integer(s))
}
print(numberOfStudents())
```

Now you can call your function, set it equal to some value which will persist outside of the function

```
newStudentList<-numberOfStudents() # you have saved your function output to this variable
```

remember you always need to set the results of a function equal to something in the current environment to capture it. If you run sd() without setting it equal to a variable, it also just prints the standard deviation but you lose access to that value.

```
x<-sd(samples) #will return a values saved to x
```